# Отслеживание изменений объекта

Tags: javascript

Как отследить изменения в объекте?

```js
function OBJ(option) {

    Object.assign(this, {
        x: 16,
        y: 32
    }, option);
}



let obj = new OBJ();
obj.x = 64;
```

При создании объекта я создаю XML. При изменении значений объекта я хочу изменять эти данные и в XML. Как это лучше всего сделать?

```js
obj.onchange = function() {
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: Я думал о создании конструктора с `set` и `get`, но не знаю будет ли вызвано событие внутри этого конструктора при изменении значений. Может кто подскажет как реализовать?

Comment: раз вы создаете объект через `Object.assign` то сеттер и геттер не поможет вам, если только вы не будите писать на каждое св-во их, а у вас они могут приходить из параметров, то есть и там нужно прописывать их. В общем идея не очень, лучше смотреть в сторону `Proxy`

Comment: @ThisMan добавил ответ где `set`, `get` и `Object.assign`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже предложил [JavaJunior](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/287120) можно использовать [геттеры и сеттеры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2). Также можно воспользоваться [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Что конкретно использовать Вам нужно решить самому исходя из Ваших задач и предпочтений.

#### Пример использования Proxy

```js
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name) {
        console.log("GETTER [target: %o, name: %o, returns: %o]", target, name, target[name]);
        return target[name];
    },
    set: function(target, name, value) {
        console.log("SETTER [target: %o, name: %o, value: %o]", target, name, value);
        if(name in target) {
            target[name] = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

var obj = {
  a: 0
};
var p = new Proxy(obj, handler);

p.a;
p.a = 1;
p.a;
p.b;
```

---

#### Материалы по теме

- [Определение геттеров и сеттеров](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [документация глобального объекта Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)
- полифилы [от команды Google Chrome](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill) и [от Babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-proxy)
- [более подробно о Proxy и Reflect](https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy)

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант используй инкапсуляцию - переменные сделай локальными, добавь сеттеры с требуемой логикой и гетеры.

Comment: Пробовал после создания вопроса. Сеттер и геттер использует вызов функции. Например, я не могу использовать сеттер x, мне придётся писать set X() или менять на что-то другое, а опций много, на каждую функции писать не алё. Хотя вызов set x() работал, правда геттер по нему же undefined :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var handler = {
 
    get: function(target, name) {
        console.log("GETTER [target: %o, name: %o, returns: %o]", target, name, target[name]);
        return target[name];
    },
 
    set: function(target, name, value) {
        console.log("SETTER [target: %o, name: %o, value: %o]", target, name, value);
        if(name in target) {
            target[name] = value;
            return true;
        }
  
        return false;
    }
}



function OBJ(option) {

    Object.assign(this, {
        x: 16,
        y: 32
    }, option);

    return new Proxy(this, handler);
}



let obj = new OBJ();
obj.x;
obj.x = 64;
```